# Wrap Text in a UITableView in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to wrap text of the cells in the UITableView. I am using the following code but the alignment of cells isnt coming proper now how to I change the Height of the cell dynamically? I noticed that there is an inbuilt method -(CGFloat) cellHeightForRow in tableView delegate but I can I take in text and set height dynamically since I have text of variable length in my JSON data

> 

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    if (cell == nil) {  
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];  
    }  
    [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
             reuseIdentifier: @"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    NSDictionary *person = [myPeople objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 

    NSString *name = [person valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [person valueForKey:@"time"];
    return cell; 
}
```

This is what I have tried so far :

> 

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSDictionary *person = [myPeople objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
    NSString *cellText    =[person valueForKey:@"text"];
    UIFont *cellFont      = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-neuve" size:21.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize      = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    int buffer  = 10;
    return labelSize.height + buffer;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [commentView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 6;
        cell.textLabel.font          = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-neuve" size:21.0];
        [cell.textLabel setMinimumFontSize:13.0];
        [cell.textLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
    } 

    NSDictionary *person = [myPeople objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 

    NSString *personName = [person valueForKey:@"text"];
        cell.textLabel.text = personName;
   // cell.detailTextLabel.text = [person valueForKey:@"date"];

    return cell; 
}
```

Still the output looks too clumpsy and tight

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: function. The first time you create your cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.font          = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21.0];
}
```

You'll notice that also I set the number of lines for the label to 0.  This lets it use as many lines as it needs.

You also need to specify how large your `UITableViewCell` will be, so do that in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText    = @"some text which is part of cell display";
    UIFont *cellFont      = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21.0];    
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize      = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    int buffer  = 10;
    return labelSize.height + buffer;
}
```

I added an extra `10` to my returned cell height because I like a little buffer around my text.

**UPDATE:** If the output is looking too tight & clumpsy then do this -

```
[cell.textLabel setMinimumFontSize:13.0];
[cell.textLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: I used [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:6] and cell.detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0 but its still the same.

Comment: I had used UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle as I want time as a subtitle

Comment: cool no problem. try the rest of my solution `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` or `Default` should not matter

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong .. 
 NSString *cellText    = @"some text which is part of cell display";
should be replaced with the json data that I want to display? Correct?

Comment: yes. what i have put is just a template, a sample. you need to modify that to the text which you will be displaying...

Comment: I have pasted my modifies code above and the output still remains clumpsy - Please let me know where am I still going wrong

Answer (score 0):

To change the height of your cell you need to change its frame in the cellForRowAtInexPath and make sure the label has the right auto sizing flags.